# awk: add new column, including header

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
name measurement gender duration
a 1 m 55
b 1 f 54
c 2 m 53
... etc
```

I want to use awk to add a column, which has the same value for every row, except the first (the header). Let's say I want to add the column new_column with the value 99 for every row, so the output file looks like this:

```
name measurement gender duration new_column
a 1 m 55 99
b 1 f 54 99
c 2 m 53 99
... etc
```

This sounds like a job for awk... but I haven't been able to figure out how. Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{s=(NR==1)?"new_column":"99";$0=$0 OFS s}1' file
name measurement gender duration new_column
a 1 m 55 99
b 1 f 54 99
c 2 m 53 99
```

Comment: Thank you! But it's missing the header of the new column (which should be new_column)

Comment: Ha, I didn't notice there's a new_column appended, try my edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this `awk`comand:

```
awk 'NR==1{$(NF+1)="new column"} NR>1{$(NF+1)="99"}1' file
```

Comment: Nice! What does that trailing 1 do? [got it! https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/86822-awk-syntax-doubt-trailing-1-value.html]

Answer (score 2):

You could golf it like this (assuming you have no empty lines):

```
awk '$++NF=NR==1?"new_column":99' infile
```

Output:

```
name measurement gender duration new_column
a 1 m 55 99
b 1 f 54 99
c 2 m 53 99
```

Comment: I had to fix the separator and quote 99 as following: awk -F="\t" '$++NF=NR==1?"\tpicks":"\t0"' infile

Comment: @fred: not really, just add `-v OFS='\t'` to the command

Comment: Yep! Or alternatively: awk -F="\t" '{OFS="\t"} $++NF=NR==1?"picks":"0"' infile, but I still with quotes.