# how to add two colums using awk?

Tags: linux, awk, command

my file is

```
id 
123
456
7632
2345
```

and I need add two columns with zeros, thus my new file will be:

```
id   sire dam
123   0    0 
456   0    0
7632  0    0
2345  0    0
```

Thank you

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems in their questions so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [awk: add new column, including header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220452/awk-add-new-column-including-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not elegant, but does what you're asking:

```
cat rami
id 
123
456
7632
2345
```

Run like this:

```
awk '$1~/id/{printf "id   sire  dam\n"} $1~/[0-9]/{printf "%-5d 0     0\n",$1} ' rami
id   sire  dam
123   0     0
456   0     0
7632  0     0
2345  0     0
```

To output to a new file just add  `> rami.new` behind the `rami` in the awk invocation ...